# why gettype(10.5 + 10.5); returns double? not integer

Tags: php, integer, double, gettype

when I tried to

`gettype(10.5 + 10.5);`

it returns double or float
but the summation of 10.5 + 10.5 = 21 which is actually an integer

Comment: doubles/floats/longs will not automatically convert to an integer unless explicitly told to do so. This can be done via "type casting" or by using math functions (such as `round`, `floor`, `ceil`) depending on your expected result. Think of it like `gettype("1" . "0")` which will show "string" even though it *looks* like an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gettype() is a function that lets you see the data type.

You add a double (10.5), and another double (10.5), you get yet another double (21.0), which is what the function returns you.

More details can be found here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php